# Select values from a list that don't exist in DB Table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a list of values. I am trying to select from that list all values that do not occur in a table.

for instance

`var_nos ['Z1234', 'Z1235,  'Z1236']
select * 
from db_table
where db_idno not in var_nos`
Is this possible?

** after reading, I'm not sure this makes sense.  I want to return the value from `var_nos` that did not appear in POHED.

Possibly SQL isn't the best way to handle this?

Comment: All is possible in SQL... Where are your list of values? In a table? In a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outer join should do it:

```
with var_nos (no) as ( values ('Z1234'), ('Z1235'),  ('Z1236'))
select no 
from var_nos
left outer join 
db_table
  on db_table.db_idno = var_nos.no
where db_table.db_idno is null
```

Alternatively:

```
select no 
from table ( values ('Z1234'), ('Z1235'),  ('Z1236')) as var_nos (no)
where not exists (
  select 1 from db_table where db_table.db_idno = var_nos.no
)
```

P.S. Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a list, you could declare a temporary table if you want.
However, you can achieve the same result from the following query. It's not as elegant as creating a temp variable for the list you want to exclude from your results.

```
SELECT * FROM db_table
WHERE db_idno NOT IN (SELECT db_idno FROM db_table WHERE db_idno NOT IN ('Z1234', 'Z1235,  'Z1236'))
```

I have tested this in MySQL and it works. Let me know how it goes

Comment: why the inner query -- just not in in main query

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'not in'.

```
select * 
from db_table where db_idno not in (
    select * from (
        select 'Z1234' db_idno   
        union select 'Z1235'
        union select 'Z1236' 
    ) exclude
)
```

Tested on MySQL.

Comment: you have 3 queries here an only need one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNNEST on an array to turn it into a table

```
SELECT *
FROM db_table
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(var_nos AS T(var_nos)) ON T.var_nos = db_table.var_nos
WHERE T.var_nos is null
```

This will only work in an SP.